# React - not able to get the latest parameter value of the function

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a function in react that returns an html element

I'm facing a weird problem. I'm getting the wrong parameter value when I console it

```
export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    accordion1: [{ id: undefined, value: "" }],
    accordion2: [{ id: undefined, value: "" }]
  });

  const textJSX = (heading) => {
    const key = heading === "Accordion 1" ? "accordion1" : "accordion2";
    return (
      <TextField
        label="Enter Details"
        placeholder="Name, date and quote"
        size="small"
        fullWidth
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log("key", key, heading);
          const temp = { ...values };
          temp[key] = [{ ...temp[key]?.[0], value: e.target.value }];
          setValues(temp);
        }}
        value={values?.[key]?.[0]?.value || ""}
      />
    );
  };

  const customImageJSX = (heading) => {
    const key = heading === "Accordion 1" ? "accordion1" : "accordion2";
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        {values[key]?.[0].id ? (
          <img className="h-12 w-12" src={values[key]?.[0].id} />
        ) : (
          <label htmlFor="attachment-button-file">
            <input
              className="hidden"
              id="attachment-button-file"
              // type="file"
              onClick={(e) => {
                console.log("key", key, heading);
                const temp = { ...values };
                temp[key] = [
                  {
                    ...(temp[key][0] || {}),
                    id: imgData
                  }
                ];
                setValues(temp);
              }}
            />
            <CloudUploadOutlinedIcon fontSize="large" />
          </label>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const acc = (options) => {
    const {
      defaultExpanded,
      heading,
      title1 = "Notes",
      title2 = "Image Load"
    } = options;
    return (
      <Accordion defaultExpanded={defaultExpanded}>
        <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
          <Typography
            color="InfoText"
            variant="h6"
            className="font-semibold"
            style={{ marginTop: "-10px" }}
          >
            {heading}
          </Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails style={{ marginTop: "-30px" }} className="">
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            variant="body1"
            className="font-semibold text-lg mb-5 mt-10"
          >
            {title1}
          </Typography>
          {textJSX(heading)}

          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            variant="body1"
            className="font-semibold text-lg mb-5 mt-10"
          >
            {title2}
          </Typography>

          {customImageJSX(heading)}
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {acc({ heading: "Accordion 1" })}
      {acc({ heading: "Accordion 2" })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I'm calling the acc function two times with different heading. Based on the parameter I will decide in which object that needs to be stored

When I do some thing in 2nd function (accordion)
For eg. In the text field which is inside textJSX that gives the correct parameter. But if I stimulate image load I'm getting the first parameter value though I'm doing in second function (accordion) resulting the images tored in accordion 1 but expected to be shown in accordion 2

**I have uploaded the above code in code sandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/accordin-file-attachment-m86lwg

Remember to add the text and image in Accordion 2 to see the issue what I mentioned

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the same id twice, ids must be unique

When you click on `<label htmlFor="attachment-button-file">` it looks for the first item with id `attachment-button-file` so it always selects the first one on the page

To fix that, use unique ids:

```
<label htmlFor={`attachment-button-file-${key}`}>
```

```
<input
  className="hidden"
  id={`attachment-button-file-${key}`}
  { /* ... */ }
/>
```